# BASS_FX_GetVersion() не дает программе запуститься

Tags: c++, qt, bass.dll

имеется работающая программа на QT с библиотекой BASS. Решил подключить bass_fx.

Как и в документации, после `BASS_Init` вызываю `BASS_FX_GetVersion()`, QT говорит "программа неожиданно завершилась".

```cpp
BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, channel.win, NULL);

if (HIWORD(BASS_FX_GetVersion())!=BASSVERSION) {
    qDebug()<<"wrong bassfx version";
}
```

все это происходит в конструкторе mainwindow. MinGW32

Comment: Бинарная несовместмость кода вашей проги и либы

Comment: Можете пояснить, пожалуйста @AlexanderChernin

Comment: Либа скомпилина одним компилятором, программа другим, например.

Comment: *"программа неожиданно завершилась"* - и на какой строке это происходит? Также приведите стек вызовов. ¿Из чего вы вообще это все собирали?

Comment: @user7860670 дебагер даже не запускается

Comment: ¿Может забыли скопировать надлежащие .dll в папку с .exe?

Comment: @user7860670 нет пробовал и с x32 и c x64 дллкой